# SheetJS format numbers with commas but without decimals

Tags: format, numbers, sheetjs

I know how to do a number with some decimal digits (after dot) like:

```
{
  t: 'n',
  v: 1234567.87654,
  z: '###,###,##0.00'
}
```

This will return the result **1,234,567.88**. But I want to have **no** decimals **with** commas. So, in this aforementioned case it should be **1,234,568**.

Can't understand, which 'z' will help in my case - z: '###,###,###,##0' doesn't work.

I know I can format it in JS and write it as a string, but I need number to be a number, not string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for me works this z:

```
z: '#,##0_-;-#,##0_-;0;General'
```